# Can I use raspberry pi to filter using AI and output audio

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

I am planning to make a device that can take a voice input and then running through a raspberry pi to filter it using AI before playing the filtered speech through speakers. Since I am relatively new to raspberry pi, I am not sure if it can handle/have the functionality to do this.

If it was possible, what are some recommended libraries/methods I can use?

Comment: it is a Linux computer ... looks for libraries in the Linux realm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TensorFlow: TensorFlow is an open-source machine learning library that can be used to train and deploy deep learning models for speech processing. TensorFlow has a Python API that can be used on a Raspberry Pi. You can use it to train and test your model for speech recognition, filtering, and other speech-related tasks.

Keras: Keras is a high-level neural networks library that runs on top of TensorFlow. It provides an easy-to-use API that allows you to quickly build and test your models. Keras can be used for speech processing tasks such as speech recognition, speech filtering, and speech enhancement.

PyAudio: PyAudio is a Python library that provides a way to play and record audio using Python. It can be used to capture voice input, process it using AI algorithms, and then output the filtered speech through speakers.

Python Speech Recognition: Python Speech Recognition is a library that can be used to recognize speech using a Raspberry Pi's microphone. It supports multiple speech recognition engines, including Google Speech Recognition, Wit.ai, and Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition.

Librosa: Librosa is a Python library for analyzing and processing audio signals. It provides tools for feature extraction, time-frequency analysis, and signal processing. You can use Librosa for tasks such as noise reduction, voice separation, and speaker identification.

Comment: I think this is more of a "might be possible" answer rather than an is.  Have you actually run all this stuff on a Pi in order to do realtime audio filtering and speech rec?

Comment: TRY THEM brother I simply gave suggestions.